# Как исправить ошибку при создании проекта на Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pycharm

Решил установить *Pycharm*, нажимаю создать проект в другом диске, и мне выдает ошибку:

> Error creating Django application: Error on Python side. 
> Exit code: 1, err: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/snap/pycharm-professional/364/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/_jb_django_project_creator.py", line 10, in   os.mkdir(path) 
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/tweu/Новый' out:

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй войти под рутом. Мне это помогло.

Comment: а как это сделать?

Comment: Как видно у тебя это Linux. Просто запусти из под пользователя root.

Comment: Или через консоль линукс. Вводишь в неё `sudo -i` в консоли и вводишь пароль. А дальше `pycharm`. После чего у тебя будет открыть PyCharn от рута.

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Может кому-то на Windows поможет. Более простой вариант без всяких консолей.

[image: right click]